# Anchor tag use to scroll in an element inside a loop

Tags: php, html, css

Faced a problem when working on .xml file parsing in PHP
What can i put in the ancher tag in that case :

```
<?php
 foreach ($xml->issue as $issue ) {
  echo '<a name="$issue->id"></a>';
   //rest of code
}
 <a href="# "> //i dont know what to put after the "Diese".
?>
```

i want to scroll to an element inside the loop .

Comment: It's very unclear what you want to achieve, but `<a href="#something">` works with `<a id="something">`

Comment: for easch element in the loop i attributed for it it's id as 'name' so i can scorll to it after .

Comment: it worked with name in another example .

Comment: @user3816341 Yes, it worked using `name` because this is the old HTML4 way. Most browsers still do understand it, but you should not use it anymore. Rely on IDs to set up a jump target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your `<a href>` tag is empty. And because of that, you won't see any links on your page:

```
<a href="example.com">TEXT HERE!!!</a>
```

Second, in `PHP`, it is not valid to introduce variables in single quoted strings, like you did. Iterpreter will not recognize them as variables and therefore will not convert them to their values. My solution (take a look at quoting style):

```
foreach ($xml->issue as $issue ) {
  echo '<a name="'.$issue->id.'">some link</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using quotes and double-quotes wrong.

```
<?php
foreach ($xml->issue as $issue) 
{
    // This will work - '.$var.'
    echo '<a href="#" name="'.$issue->id.'"></a>';
    // And this
    echo "<a href=\"#\" name=\"$issue->id\"></a>";
    // And this
    echo "<a href=\"#\" name=\"{$issue->id}\"></a>";

    // These will fail
    echo '<a href="#" name="$issue->id"></a>';
    echo '<a href="#" name=\"$issue->id\"></a>';
    echo '<a href="#" name="{$issue->id}"></a>';
}
?>
```